# Why won't a div within card go to full height in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, height

Trying to set a `div` to fill the full column but having no luck. This is my current code, any ideas?

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 my-auto">
      <div style="text-align: center;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.03);" class="h-100">Some date</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 px-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Some event</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More info</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It ends up like this:

[image]

I've tried setting the **height** to **100%** on the **text-align** `div` but with no luck.

Comment: what you're trying to achieve is called "css faux columns" or "css equal height columns" https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: Which div has to be full height? Also can you please tag your bootstrap version, 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to remove the `my-auto` from the `col-4` element and replace the target div (that one having `text-align`) by this code:

```
 <div style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.03);" class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
   Some date
 </div>
```

**Example:**

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.03);" class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
        Some date
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 px-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Some event</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More info</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

However, I will just add the custom `background-color` to the `col-4` element and center his content like on next example (removing the inner `div`). I believe this way is more clean:

```css
.custom-bg {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 custom-bg d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        Some date
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 px-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Some event</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More info</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `d-flex` for display:flex on the column content, and then the flexbox utils to center it...

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div style="text-align: center;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.03);" class="h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
          Some date
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 px-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Some event</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More info</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/bfj3rHZ3q8